# represent parent and child relation as dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary. I want to convert this list into dictionary using parent and child relation. I have try many time. But its difficult for me.
Thanks in advance for solving the problem.

Input =

```
data = [
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "label": "Property",
        "index": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "label": "Find Property",
        "index": 1,
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "label": "Add Property",
        "index": 2,
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": 4,
        "label": "Offer",
        "index": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": 5,
        "label": "My Offer",
        "index": 1,
        "parent_id": 4
    },
    {
        "_id": 6,
        "label": "Accept",
        "index": 1,
        "parent_id": 5
    }
]
```

I have a list of dictionary. I want to convert this list into dictionary using parent and child relation. I have try many time. But its difficult for me.
Thanks in advance for solving the problem.

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "label": "Property",
        "index": 1,
        "children" : [
            {
                "_id": 2,
                "label": "Find Property",
                "index": 1
            },
            {
                "_id": 3,
                "label": "Add Property",
                "index": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": 4,
        "label": "Offer",
        "index": 2,
        "children" : [
            {
                "_id": 5,
                "label": "My Offer",
                "index": 1,
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "_id": 6,
                        "label": "Accept",
                        "index": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: Will you show at least some `for i in ...` loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this. Keep in mind that this solution also affects the original `data` list.

```
parents = list()
# First, create a new dict where the key is property id and the value
# is the property itself.
indexed = {d["_id"]:d for d in data}
for id_, item in indexed.items():
    # If a property doesn't have "parent_id" key it means that
    # this is the root property, appending it to the result list.
    if "parent_id" not in item:
        parents.append(item)
        continue
    # Saving parent id for convenience.
    p_id = item["parent_id"]
    # Adding a children list if a parent doesn't have it yet.
    if "children" not in indexed[p_id]:
        indexed[p_id]["children"] = list()
    indexed[p_id]["children"].append(item)
```

And the result is:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(parents)
[{'_id': 1,
  'children': [{'_id': 2, 'index': 1, 'label': 'Find Property', 'parent_id': 1},
               {'_id': 3, 'index': 2, 'label': 'Add Property', 'parent_id': 1}],
  'index': 1,
  'label': 'Property'},
 {'_id': 4,
  'children': [{'_id': 5,
                'children': [{'_id': 6,
                              'index': 1,
                              'label': 'Accept',
                              'parent_id': 5}],
                'index': 1,
                'label': 'My Offer',
                'parent_id': 4}],
  'index': 2,
  'label': 'Offer'}]
```